# Vader Sentiment with multiple PDF

Tags: python-3.x

I have recently merged 20 pdf in 1 pdf via adobe. I have import the pdf in python with this code.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
pdf_file = open ('/Users/cj/Desktop/PEI.pdf','rb')
newfile=open('rjtjj.txt','w')
pdf_reader= PdfFileReader (pdf_file)
pdf_writer= PdfFileWriter()
print(pdf_reader.numPages) 
n=pdf_reader.getNumPages()
for i in range(0, n-1):    
# pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(i))
gft=pdf_reader.getPage(i)
newfile.write(gft.extractText())
pdf_file.close()
newfile.close()
```

I'm trying to use Vadersentiment to analyse the pdf. What i want to do is analyse individually the 20 pdf that are merged into 1.

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
with open('rjtjj.txt', 'r') as f:
for line in f.read().split("\n"):
vs=analyzer.polarity_scores(line)
```

I know my code is wrong, because it only gives me the first line of the entire pdf. I am new to this, i would really appreciate your help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem really isn't about Vader sentiment analysis -- it is about correct extraction of text from a PDF.

Postscript's forth interpreter is Turing-complete, so some PDF documents are "hard" to parse. You didn't post your PDF so we can only guess at the issue. You might try using poppler's `pdftotext` command line utility instead. Ubuntu calls the package "poppler-utils"; on mac you would use `brew install poppler`. Running through pdf2ps & ps2ascii will sometimes offer different, and helpful, results.

If you continue to find it difficult to retrieve proper text from the PDF, you may want to contact whoever produced the PDF and settle on supplying the same information in a revised format.

Comment: I have installed poppler with home brew. What code should i use?  can i use it on python?

Comment: I was suggesting two things: (1) The PDF format can be "really hard" to parse ascii text from, and (2) different PDF parsers come at it from different directions, so one might win in a certain situation, like table formatted pages, where another parser happens to lose. You didn't disclose the PDF of interest, nor how it was produced, nor how it might be produced through alternate means, including output to .TXT or to .CSV. If `$ pdftotext PEI.pdf` wins, and that is a big "if", then python could simply consume the resulting PEI.txt ascii text, without needing a PDF library at all.